# Android: Updating a menu item programmatically results in NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, menuitem

I am working on a `RecylcerView` and `CardView`. The cards contain ImageView. I also have an menu-item that is declared as an action and whose title is set to 0. What I want to achieve is that when I click on the image its position should be added to an array and the title of menu-item should be the size of array.

Below is the my menu.xml code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    ...

    <item 
      android:id="@+id/action_down_list" 
      android:title="@string/action_down_list"
      android:orderInCategory="100" 
      app:showAsAction="withText|always" 
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_download" />
</menu>
```

Below is the Adapter class code from which I am running the `onClickListner` code:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    List<String> abc = new ArrayList<String>();
    ...      
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ...
        viewHolder.imgView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                String img_id = images.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                MenuItem dl_menu = (MenuItem) view.findViewById(R.id.action_down_list);

                abc.add(img_id);
                dl_menu.setTitle(Integer.toString(abc.size()));

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But when I run my program it gives an `java.lang.NullPointerException`. I have different kinds of method but still no solution.

Comment: Menu doest work like that. You need to implement onCreatOptionMenu in activity to tell your activity about the menu.

Comment: These methods are implemented in the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line.

```
MenuItem dl_menu = (MenuItem) view.findViewById(R.id.action_down_list);
```

You tried to find a menu item in view that does not have it. There is no easy way to get access to menu from adapter.

Easiest way in your situation is to create in your adapter a set method for menu,

```
public void setMenu(Menu menu){
   this.menu = menu;
}
```

and call it for your adapter in `onCreateOptionsMenu` callback, be sure that your adapter initialized before it. After that you could write:

```java
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
   List<String> abc = new ArrayList<String>();
   Menu menu;
   ...      
   @Override
   public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     ...
     viewHolder.imgView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                String img_id = images.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                MenuItem dl_menu = menu.findItem(R.id.action_down_list);

                abc.add(img_id);
                dl_menu.setTitle(Integer.toString(abc.size()));

                return true;
            }
        });
```

But a preferred way from my point of view is using smth like [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to send to Activity or Fragment an intent with information what should be done with a menu item. So in this way adapter will don't have direct access to menu.

Comment: I don't want to send an intent because it will load the MainActivity again and again for every LongClick on the card. I will try to implement what you have mentioned above and get back with the result.

Comment: @RattusRattus intents in Android is not only for opening new Activity. You could just send it to existing Activity and catch it using BroadcastReceiver http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: Oh, I didn't read your answer clearly, that's my stupidity. LocalBroadcastManager does the trick. Thanks